# Can the vanilla JS date object be used normally in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, calendar

I'm trying to get the last date of the current month so I can accurately display calendar days so I'm using the vanilla JS date object. However, from what I've seen by console logging the date object, it seems as though it's a completely different object, presumably a react object. So how can I access the date object?

I've tried using the toString method to unwrap the date object into a string which didn't work because it turns into an array with the object in it.

```
componentDidMount() {
    let date;
    date = new Date(2019, 11, 5);
    console.log(date)
}
```

I expect the date object to be outputted instead of the unknown object

EDIT:

The unknown object looks like this in the console:

```
{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "div", key: null, ref: null, 
props: {…}, …}
```

DOUBLE EDIT:

Here's the  minimum reproducible code.

So while doing this I figured out that the date changes from the default 
date structure 
Ex. Mon May 27 2019 16:00:56 etc. to the other object when I import in the Date component for some reason.

File App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Calendar from "./Calendar"

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Calendar />
        </div>    

    )
}

export default App;
```

File Calendar.js

```
import React from "react";
import Date from "./Date";    

class Calendar extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let date = new Date();
        console.log(date)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Date /> 
        )
    }
}

export default Calendar;
```

File Date.js

```
import React from "react";

function Date() {
    return (
        <div className="grid date">
            <p>1</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Date;
```

Comment: What's the problem specifically? What do you mean by "the unknown object"?

Comment: Looks like there is something else that is also named `date` which gets logged, which would be easier to spot with a [mcve].

Comment: The code is up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're importing a component as `Date` which overshadows the `Date` global object. Meaning that when looking for `Date` in the scope chain, JavaScript will stop at the module scope with your custom `Date` component instead of going up to the global scope and finding the `Date` global.

> ```
> import Date from "./Date";
> ```

An easy way to avoid that is just to change the name in which your date component is imported.

```
import React from 'react';
import DateComponent from './Date';   

class Calendar extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        // No ambiguity here anymore!
        const date = new Date();
        console.log(date);
    }

    render() {
        // Explicit component name.
        return <DateComponent />;
    }
}
```

*And to avoid any ambiguity in your project, I'd rename the `Date.jsx` file to `DateComponent.jsx` as well.*

---

Another way to avoid this ambiguity is to use the `window` global object properties explicitly.

```
import React from 'react';
import Date from './Date';   

class Calendar extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        // No ambiguity here anymore!
        const date = new window.Date();
        console.log(date);
    }

    render() {
        // Explicit component name.
        return <Date />;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object has built-in methods you can use to format the date into a string:

```
componentDidMount() {
    let date = new Date();
    console.log(date.toLocaleDateString()) // "5/27/2019"
}
```

Comment: Yeah, so another thing is that when I use date method, I always get an error saying the method doesn't exist!?

Comment: @Elijah.S please include a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: For sure, doing so now!

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    date: ""
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      date: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)
    });
  }
  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.date}</div>;
  }
}
```

Remember there are tons of ways to achieve this.  But keeping it Vanilla flavoured as per OP's request.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I figured out the problem and the simplicity of it almost makes me wanna bash my head. Though I'm not sure about the specifics, it seems the naming of the Date component was interfering with the date object which is being instantiated. So I am assuming that somehow, although I was trying to output the Date object, I was actually outputting the Date component, hence the unknown object being the Date component with its corresponding classes grid date. If anyone can clarify what's going on in the nitty gritty, I'd love to hear it! Also, thank you for all your replies!

Comment: I wrote an answer which confirms this, and shows a working example.

Answer (score -2):

Yes Dates are used normally in React.

One way to work with dates would be the moment.js library. So you can do something like:

```
componentDidMount() {
    let date;
    date = new Date(2019, 11, 5);
    let formatted_date = moment(date).format('MMMM Do, YYYY | h:mm a') 
    console.log(formatted_date)
}
```

Comment: `moment` is great -- be careful with phrases like "the best way" because it may not be in the OP's case. `moment` also has a significant cost in terms of the weight of the library, which is something to consider.